# R: Order by new variable created in Data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to understand why can't I order by a new variable that I create in the same line.

Currently I need to write two lines, one for creating the new variable and then for ordering it.

Can this be done in the same line in **data.table**:

```
DF <- data.table(ID = c(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2), Value = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
newDF <- DF[order(-Count), .(Count = .N), by = ID] 

# Gives error: Error in eval(v, x, parent.frame()) : object 'Count' not found


# Works Correctly
newDF <- DF[, .(Count = .N), by = ID]
newDF <- newDF[order(-Count)]

> newDF
    ID Count
1:  1     6
2:  2     3
```

Comment: The reason for this behavior is because the ith element is evaluated first so you could operate over subsets. Hence, first data.table tries to evaluate `order(-Count)` and only then move to `, .(Count = .N), by = ID`, but because `Count` wasn't yet created, it throws the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply chain both of the operations in a single line,

```
DF[, .(Count = .N), by = ID][order(-Count)]
```