# How to subset and order rows in one data.table call?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm learning data.table and am trying to subset and re-order grouped data while calculating averages, all in one data.table statement.

I got the flight data from [here](https://github.com/arunsrinivasan/flights/wiki/NYC-Flights-2014-data) while following along in this [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

From the tutorial,

**How can we get the average arrival and departure delay for each orig,dest pair for each month for carrier code “AA”?**

```
ans <- flights[carrier == "AA",
        .(mean(arr_delay), mean(dep_delay)),
        by = .(origin, dest, month)]
ans
#      origin dest month         V1         V2
#   1:    JFK  LAX     1   6.590361 14.2289157
#   2:    LGA  PBI     1  -7.758621  0.3103448
#   3:    EWR  LAX     1   1.366667  7.5000000
#   4:    JFK  MIA     1  15.720670 18.7430168
#   5:    JFK  SEA     1  14.357143 30.7500000
#  ---                                        
# 196:    LGA  MIA    10  -6.251799 -1.4208633
# 197:    JFK  MIA    10  -1.880184  6.6774194
# 198:    EWR  PHX    10  -3.032258 -4.2903226
# 199:    JFK  MCO    10 -10.048387 -1.6129032
# 200:    JFK  DCA    10  16.483871 15.5161290
```

This makes sense to me. However, I want to improve on this by organizing the flights which departed from the same origin together. Following the schema of...

```
data.table(subset, select/compute, group by)
```

I came up with this:

```
flights[(carrier=="AA")[order(origin, dest)], 
       .(Arrival_Delay=mean(arr_delay), Depart_Delay=mean(dep_delay)), 
       by=.(origin, dest, month)]
```

But my call to order doesn't seem to have done anything. Why?

I can achieve this in dplyr with:

```
 flights %>%
  filter(carrier=="AA") %>%
  group_by(origin, dest, month) %>%
  summarize(Arrival_Delay=mean(arr_delay), Depart_Delay=mean(dep_delay)) %>%
  as.data.table()
```

I'm curious how to do this in data.table and why my approach did not work.

Comment: put the `[order()]` call at the end of the chain: `flights[(carrier=="AA"), 
       .(Arrival_Delay=mean(arr_delay), Depart_Delay=mean(dep_delay)), 
       by=.(origin, dest, month)][order(origin, dest)]`

Comment: That worked! Although I'm wondering what's wrong with (carrier=="AA")[order(origin, dest)] as a re-ordering of those logicals...

Comment: @PanFrancisco: read the comment in this to understand why it won't work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46462054/r-order-by-new-variable-created-in-data-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `data.table`, you can use `keyby` when you want to sort a result after a by operation. From `help("data.table", package = "data.table")`

> *keyby*
>   Same as by, but with an additional setkey() run on the by columns of the result, for convenience. **It is common practice to use 'keyby=' routinely when you wish the result to be sorted.**

You could then use `keyby` instead of `by` in your code

```r
library(data.table)
# get the data from the web
flights <- fread("https://github.com/arunsrinivasan/flights/wiki/NYCflights14/flights14.csv")
# keyby will call setkey and then sort your result
ans <- flights[carrier == "AA",
               .(mean(arr_delay), mean(dep_delay)),
               keyby = .(origin, dest, month)]
ans
#>      origin dest month         V1         V2
#>   1:    EWR  DFW     1   6.427673 10.0125786
#>   2:    EWR  DFW     2  10.536765 11.3455882
#>   3:    EWR  DFW     3  12.865031  8.0797546
#>   4:    EWR  DFW     4  17.792683 12.9207317
#>   5:    EWR  DFW     5  18.487805 18.6829268
#>  ---                                        
#> 196:    LGA  PBI     1  -7.758621  0.3103448
#> 197:    LGA  PBI     2  -7.865385  2.4038462
#> 198:    LGA  PBI     3  -5.754098  3.0327869
#> 199:    LGA  PBI     4 -13.966667 -4.7333333
#> 200:    LGA  PBI     5 -10.357143 -6.8571429
```